# Colon in javascript callback

Tags: javascript

I'm using the data layer on google maps with point geometries that occasionally use the same coordinates. To access all of the features at a given coordinate I'm trying to use a port of OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier for the data layer instead of markers called [OverlappingFeatureSpiderfier](https://github.com/slovely/OverlappingFeatureSpiderfier).

I'm have problems adding the click handler for the data layer. In the documentation it calls for:

```
ofs.addListener("click", function(event: google.maps.Data.MouseEvent) {
  var theFeatureThatWasClicked = event.feature;
}
```

Besides the missing parenthesis,  I can't figure out what's going on with that colon in the callback. Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). Look in the 'src' folder of the project you linked to and you will see a `.ts` file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon syntax there is a [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) type annotation.

To use that with vanilla JS, just put `function(event)`.

Comment: I thought that might be it. Thanks.